# How do I change the values for horizontal and vertical movement during a game in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, character

I am trying to create a game in Unity, so far I designed the terrain and tried to move the player. The problem is the player is moving, but when I turn in a certain direction the directions would have to update.

Like the key <kbd>A</kbd> should still move forward just that now the x-axis would be forward. So my question is how can I update the axis and directions in my C# script on which the keys let the player move during the game?

Edit:

```
public float turnSpeed = 20f;

Animator m_Animator;
Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;

Vector3 m_Movement;
Quaternion m_Rotation = Quaternion.identity;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //User pressed left/right arrow or A/D generates an Input which is called here
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); //User pressed up/down or W/S generates also an Input between -1 and 1 which is called here

    m_Movement.Set(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
    m_Movement.Normalize();

    bool hasHorizontalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(horizontal, 0f);
    bool hasVerticalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(vertical, 0f);


    bool isWalking = hasHorizontalInput || hasVerticalInput;
    m_Animator.SetBool("IsWalking", isWalking);


    Vector3 desiredForward = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, m_Movement, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    m_Rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(desiredForward);


}

private void OnAnimatorMove()
{
    m_Rigidbody.MovePosition(m_Rigidbody.position + m_Movement * m_Animator.deltaPosition.magnitude);
    m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rotation);
}
```

I tryed to rotate the virtual camera, and hoped it would fix the moveing problem, which it obviously didn't.

Comment: thats why you turn and use vector3.forward

Comment: So this is my code rn do I have to check for every frame if the horizontal/vertical input is -1 or 1 and only if it is move it forward/back/left/right or can I just move forward every time?

Comment: Like can I say instead of m_Movement.Set(...); -> transform.position += m_Movement.forward * Time.deltaTime; ?

Comment: take a read up on vector3.forward.

Comment: Oh! It doesn't work like this, I'd have to type something with Vector3.forward... The thing is I tried many different things now and I still have no clue I found something that made sense. It was like I'd have to move my character on his own axis not the ones of the map, but I am so confused now on how to make this work... Do you have any idea, how I can move him on his own axis or what I am doing wrong in my code, by any chance? If not thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Cause I can move him either forwards now or I can rotate him but I don't get it that when I rotate the new direction he is faceing is for key W only at the start he moves forwards if I press W after I turn left by pressing A and then press W again I turn right and than move forward instead of moving forward directly

Comment: as I said, if you turn, vector3.forward is forward, not "north" or whatever. it is forward.

Comment: But where in my Code would I have to put that? I tried literally everywhere now and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I figured out a different way now that kinda works for anybody in the future with the same problem thats the Code:

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        //Move the Rigidbody forwards constantly at speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
        m_Rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * m_Speed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        //Move the Rigidbody backwards constantly at the speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
        m_Rigidbody.velocity = -transform.forward * m_Speed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        //Rotate the sprite about the Y axis in the positive direction
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime*m_rotationSpeed, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        //Rotate the sprite about the Y axis in the negative direction
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * Time.deltaTime*m_rotationSpeed, Space.World);
    }
```

The only problem now is if you rotate your character and hold the rotate key pressed for too long than release it it will rotate for a while...

Comment: Since you are using Rigidbody to move. Use Rigidbody.AddTorque to rotate. Test the value of Angular drag, so the player stops rotating when you leave the key.